# Best way to "Save As" or "Rename" a database in VB.NET using SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

In my application I wanted to Open an existing blank database (called "New File" - with full structure but no data), then fill the database using the application then save the database with a different name and path.  What is the most appropriate method of doing this?  I use SQLEXPRESS and VB.NET 2010.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is you want to do and why? This doesn't seem like a good idea for database...

Answer (score 0):

The best supported solution would be to use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx), which provides full programmatic control to SQL Server, and is largely (exclusively?) what Management Studio uses. Something to be aware of is the difference between the logical name and physical name of the database. You original question does not address which you are attempting to rename, but they are completely separate. For the former, there should be no active processes open in the database. For the latter, you will probably find it easiest to Detach, move the file using OS conventions, then re-Attach.